# Why does the virtual terminal fail to grow when the cols parameter of the xterm terminal component exceeds 80?

Tags: kubernetes, terminal

It is like this, I am making a k8s operation and maintenance platform, one of the functions is: click the terminal button, and then pop up a linux terminal connected with this pod. My front-end uses vue and elementui, and the terminal related component is xterm.
However, I found a problem, that is, when I create a new terminal, the parameter that controls the size of the terminal: cols, which increases to 80, the display of the virtual terminal will not continue to increase, as shown in the following figure：
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SueFi.png)
The parameters look like this：
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xayPX.png)
If the cols is greater than 80, the terminal will not continue to grow, but if the COLs is less than 80, the terminal will become smaller and smaller as the number decreases.
This is the effect when the cols value of the terminal is 40, in addition to the rows value no matter how large or small the terminal can be normally larger and smaller：
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B6chd.png)

I initially thought it was the parent component or the style, but after a long search, I found that it was not, and maybe the style problem can be ruled out
And I have the function of using the component to make it bigger or smaller, and I think there should be no mistakes
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TxQWl.png)
I look up the information shows that it may be related to the pseudo-terminal, I am learning about the relevant knowledge, is there a senior handsome and kind programmer to help me guide the direction

this is my code：

```js
import { Terminal } from "xterm";
import { FitAddon } from "xterm-addon-fit";
import { AttachAddon } from "xterm-addon-attach";
import "xterm/css/xterm.css";
//import "xterm/lib/xterm.js";
import session from "@/utils/session";
import http from "@/utils/http";
export default {
  name: "terminal",
  props: {
    namespace: String,
    pod: String,
    container: String,
    shell: String,
    cluster:Object
  },
  data() {
    return {
      term: null,
      socketUrl: "",
      socket: ""
    };
  },
  computed: {
    /*
    socketUrl() {
      let ws = window.location.href.startsWith("https://")?"wss":"ws";
      return `${ws}://${window.location.host}/api/terminal?clusterName=${this.cluster?.name}&namespace=${this.namespace}&pod=${this.pod}&container=${this.container}`;
    }
    */
    
  },
  mounted() {
    
    http.get("metrics/common/websocketHost.serv", {clusterName:this.cluster?.name}).then( response=> {
      let host = response.body.host;
      if(!host)
        host = window.location.host + "/";
      else{
        if(host.endsWith("/")==false){
          host = host + "/";
        }
      }
      this.socketUrl = `${response.body.scheme}://${host}api/terminal?clusterName=${this.cluster?.name}&namespace=${this.namespace}&pod=${this.pod}&container=${this.container}`;
      this.initTerm();
    }).catch(err=>{
      this.$message.error("终端访问地址获取失败：" + http.errorMessage(err));
    })
    
    
  },
  beforeDestroy() {
    this.socket && this.socket.close();
    this.term && this.term.dispose();
  },
  methods: {
    initTerm() {
      this.term = new Terminal({
        //rendererType: "canvas",
        rows: 40, // 行数
        cols: 80, 
        //convertEol: true, // 启用时，光标将设置为下一行的开头
        // scrollback: 50, // 终端中的回滚量
        //disableStdin: false, // 是否应禁用输入
        //windowsMode: true, // 根据窗口换行
        cursorStyle: "underline", // 光标样式
        cursorBlink: true, // 光标闪烁
        theme: {
          foreground: "#ececec", // 字体
          background: "#000000", // 背景色
          cursor: "help", // 设置光标
          lineHeight: 20
        }
      });
      //  websocket 初始化
      if (this.socketUrl === "") return;
      this.socket = new WebSocket(this.socketUrl, session.get()); // 带token发起链接
      // websocket 集成的插件
      const attachAddon = new AttachAddon(this.socket);
      this.term.loadAddon(attachAddon);
      const fitAddon = new FitAddon();
      this.term.loadAddon(fitAddon);
      this.term.open(this.$refs.terminal);
      //
      this.term.focus();
      //setTimeout(()=>{fitAddon.fit();},60)
    }
  }
};
```

```css
.xterm {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <div id="xterm" class="xterm" ref="terminal"/>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: That isn't xterm

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.